# How draw a empty bloxplot recursive with NAs

Tags: r, boxplot, na

I'm tryng to recursive boxplot but one column in the dataset is NA and return: *Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...)*

How plot a empty boxplot for that column?

Example:

```
x1<-rnorm(40,4) #complete
x2<-c(rnorm(10,1),rep(NA,10),rnorm(20,2)) #incomplete
x3<-c(rep(NA,40)) #only NA
x4<-rnorm(40,4) #complete
clas<-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10),rep(4,10))
dat<-cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,clas)
dat

for(i in 1:4){
boxplot(dat[,i]~factor(clas))
x11()
}
```

I'm really stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't know what min and max values to use for the y axis. But you can generate a fake y vector and just set border="white" to make it invisible.

```
x1<-rnorm(40,4) #complete
x2<-c(rnorm(10,1),rep(NA,10),rnorm(20,2)) #incomplete
x3<-c(rep(NA,40)) #only NA
x4<-rnorm(40,4) #complete
clas<-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10),rep(4,10))
dat<-cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,clas)
dat

for(i in 1:4){
  if(all(is.na(dat[,i]))) {
    #set y axis min and max
    y.min <- 1
    y.max <- 5
    y.vec <- c(rep(y.min, nrow(dat)- 1), y.max)
    boxplot(y.vec~factor(clas), border = "white")
  } else boxplot(dat[,i]~factor(clas))
  x11()
}
```

Comment: @TRI in that case could you please mark my answer as useful, thanks :)